# How to retrieve a file deployed in a Android App written in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

I'm starting my long journey to master Delphi Mobile Development and at this time I have a small app that collects some data and stores them in a SQLite data file. That file is correctly deployed with the app and stores all data in some tables.

Now I want to retrieve that file to analize those data in my PC, but I can't find a way to access it when I plug my Android device to my PC USB port.

Windows mounts a drive for the device, but no file or folders are shown.

The device is a Moto G4+ and it was already setup for development purposes (programmer mode on and USB debug on with Media Transfer Protocol).

How to make my SQLite file to be available to my PC?

Comment: Have you considered using Datasnap via [tethering](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/easily-connect-your-local-devices-together-with-app-tethering)?

Comment: No, because I have specific requirements to meet.

Comment: Then why not include them in your q?

Comment: I did. I said I have to use the USB port to retrieve the SQLite file after the app runs and collects data. The scenario I described is my requirement

Comment: With respect, your q did **not** say that it was a requirement to use USB, only that you have been unable to access your data that way - there is a difference.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I didn't really say it was a requirement, but I explained my scenario. I hope it's now clear that I have to work under those conditions  to consider my problem solved.

Comment: Where (which path) did you save the file to? In deployment manager, did you use assets or assets\internal?

Comment: @nolaspeaker: sorry for taking this long to answer. I used assets\internal.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to download the [Media Feature Pack for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack), if you are running a version of Windows 10 that does not include the Media Player otherwise the MTP drivers for Windows will not be installed and you won't be able to connect to the device.

Comment: So what you say is that the files will be visible in PC in the moment I have those drivers installed?

Comment: Now that I reread your question, you are trying to pull a file created by your app.  This may not be possible with MTP because of the way Android sandboxes apps and their data.  You could use ADB to pull it from a terminal.  Another approach over USB is to use Android Studio's "Device File Explorer" feature.

Comment: Strange. If this is not possible, why is it possible to mount a drive to the device pluged in the USB port? Windows indeed mounts a drive and explorer can work with it. I guessed I just had to set some kind of flag or move my files to a particular shared area, so they would appear to Windows. Am I wrong in my assumptions? My previous cell phone was a Sumsung Galaxy S2. With that, anytime I pluged it to USB I could access a number o files, like photos, movies and other files from some particular apps. They same does not happen with Moto G4+.